# How can I create a bottom navigation view like this with a Floating Action Button (FAB) containing both an icon and an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I'm currently trying to create a bottom navigation view similar to the one shown in this image:

[image]

However, I'd like to customize the FAB to not only contain an icon but also an image, as shown in this image:
[image]
I've attempted a few approaches but haven't been able to achieve the desired outcome. Could anyone provide guidance or an example of how to accomplish this?

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the same demo by referring to the blow article from the medium. It has exactly what you need.
[animated bottom navbar tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/curved-cut-out-bottom-navigation-with-animation-in-android-c630c867958c)

Comment: hmm i think it's not what i need, i just need the curve in the middle, and beside the fab in the article doesn't containing text, but thanks for answering...

Comment: you can add that part yourselt just place textviews there.

Comment: oh ok, let me try it first